# Showing the selected value on the handler of range input as the value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a range input which is having circle shaped handler. I used css to make the handler look like circle. Now that Im trying to find a way to show the value selected inside that circle. But I didn't find any way to do that even after long time. So here I am. Is there any way to do the same ? and one more thing I need to fill the colors on the left and right side of the handler based on the value selected. Can you please suggest how do i do it ? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I used

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10"/>

input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #e95e57;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I can get you part of the way there by suggesting that you add a bit of JS to create an event listener for the input and then apply the value to another element that would have to be manipulated via CSS to appear inside the circle.

Comment: In that case I ll need to move that input along with the handler right ? Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: I wish I could answer that but I just don't know if the slider itself can be tracked as far as a X,Y location is concerned.

Comment: Could you please tell more about how you want which colors to be filled?

Comment: There are 4 slider each will have different colors to be filled. I got it. Thank yo so much for ur help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that covers both aspects mentioned. You can also have multiple range inputs on the same page and all will work individually.

**Note**: I did use a couple of lines of **Markai's** code. Thanks to him.

1. HTML

   ```
   <div class="range-wrapper">
     <input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="myRange"/>
     <div class="text">1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="range-wrapper">
     <input type="range" min="0" max="10" id="mySecondRange"/>
     <div class="text">1</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. jQuery

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     updateRangeValue($('input[type=range]'));
     $('input[type=range]').on('input change',function(){
       var input = $(this);
       updateRangeValue(input);
     });    
   });
   function getRangeGradient(color1,color2,value,maximum){
     var gradient = "linear-gradient(to right, ";
     var breakPoint = (value/maximum)*100;
     var attrValue = gradient + color1 + " 0%, " + color1 + " " + breakPoint + "%, " + color2 + " " + breakPoint + "%, " + color2 + " 100%)";
     return attrValue;
   }
   function updateRangeValue(input){
     var selectedColor = "#428bca";
     var nonSelectedColor = "#ddd";
     var value = input.val();
     var maximum = input.attr('max'); 
     var inputWidth = input.width();
     var background = getRangeGradient(selectedColor, nonSelectedColor, value, maximum);
     var offLeft = Math.floor((value / maximum) * inputWidth - (((value / maximum) * inputWidth - inputWidth/2) / 100) * 24);    
     var offLeftAbs = value == maximum ? input.offset().left - 15 + offLeft : input.offset().left - 10 + offLeft;
     input.next('.text').css({'left': offLeftAbs +'px'});
     input.next('.text').html(value);
     input.css('background', background); 
   }
   ```
3. CSS

   ```
   .range-wrapper {
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 5px 0px;    
   } 
   .range-wrapper > div {
     position: relative;
     top: -15px;
     width: 5px;
   }
   .range-wrapper > .text {
     pointer-events: none;
   }
   input[type=range]{
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #428bca 0%, #428bca 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd 100%);
   }
   input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
     width: 300px;
     height: 5px;   
     border: none;
     border-radius: 3px;
   }
   input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     border: 1px solid #e95e57;
     height: 32px;
     width: 32px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: white;
     margin-top: -14px;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   input[type=range]:focus {
     outline: none;
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #428bca 0%, #428bca 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd 100%);
   }
   ```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ndr0bja/3/) link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) It was really helpful..Im delighted (y)

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest not very cross-browser solution using canvas as background:

```js
function renderValue(value) {
    var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'value', 32, 32);
        
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
    
    ctx.font = 'bold 18px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#888';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center'; 
    ctx.fillText(value, 15, 21);
}

var input = document.querySelector('input')
input.oninput = function() {
    renderValue(this.value);
}
renderValue(input.value);
```

```css
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #e95e57;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -14px;
    background: -webkit-canvas(value) no-repeat 0 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}

div.test  {
    background: -webkit-canvas(clouds) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px red solid;
}

canvas {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" data-value="3" />
```

Comment: If you use oninput it get's updated straight on dragging and not just when you release the mouse button

Comment: @DevlshOne Correct http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-canvas But I guess support is not that important because input `slider-thumb` is not going to work everywhere in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) I got what I wanted analysing all the answers :)

Comment: Do you know how to made this for few inputs? I mean how to use the different canvas for each input? Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, however it's not very convenient, as it required different canvas for each input. So one would need to create different CSS rule for `-webkit-slider-thumb` per input. Of course it's possible to create those rules dynamically, but still.

Answer (score 2):

I have kind of a solution, that should work cross browser, but it is pretty ugly and has the problem, that there is a text over the button which makes it only dragable on the sides (if somebody has a solution for this please feel free to tell):

HTML

```
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="10"/>
<div id="rangeval">0</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function updateRangeVal(){
    var offLeft = Math.floor(($('#range').val() / $('#range').attr('max')) * $('#range').width() - ((($('#range').val() / $('#range').attr('max')) * $('#range').width() - $('#range').width()/2) / 100) * 24);
    var offLeftAbs = $('#range').offset().left - 8 + offLeft;
    $('#rangeval').css({"top": ($('#range').offset().top-8)+"px", "left": offLeftAbs +"px"});
    $('#rangeval').html($('#range').val());
}

$('#range').on('input', function(){
    updateRangeVal();
});

updateRangeVal();
```

CSS

```
#rangeval{
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 300px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #e95e57;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    margin-top: -14px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avx0jdu3/)

the offsets on the slider are just for testing purposes

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) I got what I wanted analysing all the answers :)